# Run Matlab mex-Algorithm instead of Double- in Single-Precision

Tags: matlab, precision, infinite-loop, mex

I have a working Matlab C code (mex files) which currently uses double precision. Thus I replaced

`double *datOut = mxGetPr(mxOut)` by `float *datOut = (float*)mxGetData(mxOut);`,

`mxCreateDoubleMatrix` by `mxCreateNumericArray()`

and

the datatypes of the variables `double` by `float`. The only other mex-Function which is being used is `mxDuplicateArray()` but nothing else. I didn't change anything to this call... Now I have a Code running which never finishes. I stripped it down quite a bit so that I hope it's short enough that somebody could help me:

```
float myFunc(const mxArray *point, int index)
{
    float *dat = (float*)mxGetData(point);
    return dat[index]*dat[index]*dat[index];
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
    float h, f0, df1, df2, diff;

    // Input Vars #1
    float diff  = (float)mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
    float H = (float)mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);
    int index1 = (int)mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);
    int index2 = (int)mxGetScalar(prhs[4]);

    // Input Vars #2 -> Duplicate it
    mxArray *newPnt = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);
    float *newPntDat = (float*)mxGetData(newPnt);

    // ...
    // PERHAPS SOME UNIMPORANT CODE HERE ...
    // ...
    h = H;
    f0 = myFunc(prhs[0], index1);

    newPntData[ index2 ] += h;
    df1 = (myFunc(newPnt, index1)-f0)/h;
    while(true)
    {
        h /= 2;

        newPntDat[ index2 ] -= h;
        df2 = (myFunc(newPnt, index1)-f0)/h;

        // If precision is okay
        if(abs(df2-df1) <= diff)
            break;

        // Save for next loop iteration
        df1 = df2;
    }

    // Return df2-Value to Matlab
}
```

somehow it's an infinite loop and I dunno why since the precision which is defined via `diff` should be easily reachable for the given function `myFunc()`. The identicall code runs fine when using double precision with the both functions `double *datOut = mxGetPr(mxOut)` and `mxCreateDoubleMatrix`. I also tried to call the mex-Function by explicitly pass the point via `point = zeros(rows, 1, 'single');`.

Thanks very much for pointing me to the right direction or giving me ANY hint about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `abs()` with `fabs()`.

In general, in such cases, I would use `mexPrintf()` to print the values that affect the termination condition. I.e., if the above change does not help, try adding

```
mexPrintf("%g %g %g %g\n",df2,df1,diff, fabs(df2-df1));
```

Just to make sure the behavior is as you expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that could really really help me out. I'll try it later and tell you if it works.

Comment: Ah and just the question: What will `mxArray *newPnt = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);` do? Will this work even when using `float *newPntDat = (float*)mxGetData(newPnt);` when just calling the mex-Function via `myMexFunc(ones(1000, 1))` or do I have so specify the parameter 'single' to ones()?

Comment: You still have to use the 'single' parameter. Otherwise the array passed to the mex will be double by default and you cannot cast it to float (mxDuplicateArray will work either way -- the result is of the same type as the input and will be single array only if you pass a single precision array to the mex)

Comment: Okay thanks again - so that's what I thought too :) I tried it but somehow, the algorithm doesn't work when transfering it to use floats... Question: Since `H` and `diff` are input arguments (which I type-cast to floats) and are used for the abort-condition `if(abs(df2-df1) <= diff)` do I also need to somehow pass them as 'single' values? Currently I'm just using something like `myMexFunc(ones(100, 1, 'single'), 0.001, 0.0001)`...

Comment: Edit: Tried it also, but still doesn't work. So I have to look further into it with many debug outputs... Probably you cant help with any more code right?

Comment: Regarding the scalar values H and diff -- no you don't need to pass these as single. The conversion to float is OK. Did you change the abs() to fabs()? abs() is defined for ints only.